# Android Libgdx - Sigsegv 11 error on real device but no crash on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, segmentation-fault

I am currently trying to make an application with libgdx on android.

The application is working fine on emulator of android studio but there is a crash with my real phone when I do a world.destroy(body) with the library box2d.
More precisely, during the execution of the game, the application destroys 2 bodys after a collision like it is suppose to do but after 1 sec the app crash.

Here is the code of my listener of collision.

```
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

    Body a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    Body b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

    if ((BodyUtils.bodyIsWater(b) && BodyUtils.bodyIsEnemy(a))|| (BodyUtils.bodyIsEnemy(b) && BodyUtils.bodyIsWater(a))){
            if (!remove.contains(a)) {
                remove.add(a);
            }
            if (!remove.contains(b)) {
                remove.add(b);
            }
            iswater = false;
    }
    else if(BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(b) && BodyUtils.bodyIsWater(a)){
        if(!remove.contains(a)) {
            remove.add(a);
        }
        iswater=false;
    }
    else if(BodyUtils.bodyIsGround(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsWater(b)){
        if(!remove.contains(b)) {
            remove.add(b);
        }
        iswater=false;
    }
    a=null;
    b=null;
}
```

Comment about the code: Water is the bullet which shoot the ennemy. Remove is the arraylist.

Here is the code of my act method which destroy the body that are inside my arraylist of body to destroy ( the collision method but body to destroy into the arraylist ). The destroy call is into the for loop.

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);

    // Fixed timestep
    accumulator += delta;

    while (accumulator >= delta) {
        world.step(TIME_STEP, 10, 10);
        accumulator -= TIME_STEP;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < remove.size(); i++) {
        world.destroyBody(remove.get(i));
        remove.remove(i);
        /*for (int n = 0; i < y.getJointList().size; n++){
            world.destroyJoint(y.getJointList().get(n).joint);
        }*/
    }

    if(add%100==0 && !iswater) {
        Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>(world.getBodyCount());
        world.getBodies(bodies);

        for (Body body : bodies) {
            update(body);
        }
    }
    if(add%80==0){
        createEnemy();
    }

    add++;

}
```

Here is the content of the update methode :

```
private void update(Body body) {
    if (BodyUtils.bodyIsEnemy(body) && !iswater) {
        EnemyUserData z = (EnemyUserData) body.getUserData();
        Vector2 m=body.getPosition();
        if(m.x<23f){
            createWater(z,m);
            iswater=true;
        }
    }
}
```

First, I tried to figure out where to problem was from and I found that the app was not crashing if a wasn't destroying bodies. So know I know that the destroy function makes the app crash.

Here is the Sigsegv log:

```
04-03 19:01:50.068 25361-25404/com.mygdx.game A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7a99fd63c0 in tid 25404 (GLThread 3290)

                                                  [ 04-03 19:01:50.076   402:  402 W/         ]
                                                  debuggerd: handling request: pid=25361 uid=10171 gid=10171 tid=25404
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/PRA-LX1/HWPRA-H:7.0/HUAWEIPRA-LX1/C432B196:user/release-keys'
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG: pid: 25361, tid: 25404, name: GLThread 3290  >>> com.mygdx.game <<<
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7a99fd63c0
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007a99fd63c0  x1   00000000000000b8  x2   0000007899f841c0  x3   0000000000000002
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000001  x5   0000000000000001  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     x8   000000789a2e8098  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000001  x11  0000000000000001
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     x12  000000789a91d718  x13  000000789a91d7b4  x14  00000078b7ab1150  x15  0000000000000060
04-03 19:01:50.174 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     x16  000000789a2e7a18  x17  000000789a2b99d8  x18  0000000000000001  x19  0000007899f841c0
04-03 19:01:50.175 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     x20  00000078b6888760  x21  0000007899f84200  x22  0000000000000006  x23  00000078b0a86fa0
04-03 19:01:50.175 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000048  x25  604eae760b11fb4a  x26  00000078b80d5698  x27  00000078b80d5600
04-03 19:01:50.175 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     x28  000000789a91d7b0  x29  000000789a91d6d0  x30  000000789a2bd004
04-03 19:01:50.175 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     sp   000000789a91d6a0  pc   000000789a2b9a34  pstate 0000000080000000
04-03 19:01:50.180 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
04-03 19:01:50.180 1295-1316/? I/Bluetooth_framework: BluetoothManagerService:Message: 401
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000001ba34  /data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (_ZN16b2BlockAllocator8AllocateEi+92)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000001f000  /data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (_ZN7b2World10CreateBodyEPK9b2BodyDef+48)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000002f6d0  /data/app/com.mygdx.game-1/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_World_jniCreateBody+160)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000000db790  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000000d21b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000dee80  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+204)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000028cbf0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+312)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000286cac  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb1ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+444)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00000000005556e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirectRange+384)
04-03 19:01:50.181 25501-25501/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00000000000c4f94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15252)


                                      [ 04-03 19:01:50.536   402:  402 W/         ]
                                      debuggerd: resuming target 25361
```

I've also tested an emulator which have the same android version of my phone and it worked. ( it is version 7 api 24 ). So it isn't the problem.

ps: I don't destroy twice a body (I've put some condition to avoid it).

I am a noob of libgdx please help <3 (and sorry for my bad english!)

EDIT : To answers a question in the comment of  "Subrata M" here is the logcat if i put the destroy method after the update and the createEnemy().

```
04-03 20:26:59.973 29708-29747/com.mygdx.game A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7a9a07b400 in tid 29747 (GLThread 3385)
04-03 20:26:59.974 2497-2497/? I/WearableService: Wearable Services stopping

                                              [ 04-03 20:26:59.976   402:  402 W/         ]
                                              debuggerd: handling request: pid=29708 uid=10171 gid=10171 tid=29747
04-03 20:27:00.017 1600-1600/? W/HwKeyguardDragHelper: AnimationBlocked
04-03 20:27:00.025 1600-1600/? I/EventCenter: EventCenter Get :android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
04-03 20:27:00.032 1600-1600/? W/HwKeyguardDragHelper: AnimationBlocked
04-03 20:27:00.039 1600-1600/? E/DateLunarView: mDateString is: mar 3 avr
04-03 20:27:00.042 1600-1600/? E/DateLunarView: mDateString is: mar 3 avr
04-03 20:27:00.054 2572-2572/? I/HwLauncher: Model  onReceive intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }
04-03 20:27:00.054 2572-2572/? I/HwLauncher: Model  onReceive user=UserHandle{0}
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/PRA-LX1/HWPRA-H:7.0/HUAWEIPRA-LX1/C432B196:user/release-keys'
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG: pid: 29708, tid: 29747, name: GLThread 3385  >>> com.mygdx.game <<<
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7a9a07b400
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007a9a07b400  x1   00000000000000b8  x2   0000007899b36980  x3   0000000000000002
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000001  x5   0000000000000001  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     x8   000000789775e098  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000001  x11  0000000000000001
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     x12  000000789aa1a7e8  x13  000000789aa1a884  x14  00000078b7ab1150  x15  0000000000000060
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     x16  000000789775da18  x17  000000789772f9d8  x18  0000000000000001  x19  0000007899b36980
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     x20  00000078b687a270  x21  0000007899b369c0  x22  0000000000000006  x23  00000078b6a13fa0
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000048  x25  604eae760b11fb4a  x26  00000078a908ca98  x27  00000078a908ca00
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     x28  000000789aa1a880  x29  000000789aa1a7a0  x30  0000007897733004
04-03 20:27:00.079 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     sp   000000789aa1a770  pc   000000789772fa34  pstate 0000000080000000
04-03 20:27:00.087 1600-1600/? W/ExpandableNotificationRow: setActionsBackground,null == view,mPublicLayout
04-03 20:27:00.089 1600-1600/? W/ExpandableNotificationRow: setActionsBackground,null == view,mPublicLayout
04-03 20:27:00.092 1600-1600/? W/ExpandableNotificationRow: setActionsBackground,null == view,mPublicLayout
04-03 20:27:00.094 1600-1600/? W/ExpandableNotificationRow: setActionsBackground,null == view,mPublicLayout
04-03 20:27:00.097 1600-1600/? W/HwKeyguardDragHelper: AnimationBlocked
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000001ba34  /data/app/com.mygdx.game-2/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (_ZN16b2BlockAllocator8AllocateEi+92)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000001f000  /data/app/com.mygdx.game-2/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (_ZN7b2World10CreateBodyEPK9b2BodyDef+48)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000002f6d0  /data/app/com.mygdx.game-2/lib/arm64/libgdx-box2d.so (Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_World_jniCreateBody+160)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000000db790  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000000d21b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000dee80  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+204)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000028cbf0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+312)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000286cac  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb1ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+444)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00000000005556e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirectRange+384)
04-03 20:27:00.098 29868-29868/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00000000000c4f94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15252)
04-03 20:27:00.123 2572-2572/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
04-03 20:27:00.131 2572-2572/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
04-03 20:27:00.136 2572-2572/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null


                                          [ 04-03 20:27:00.390   402:  402 W/         ]
                                          debuggerd: resuming target 29708
```

EDIT2 : I asked two friends to test the app. the first has got a oneplus 3t and it doesn't crash. The other has got a Huawei Mate 9 and it crash.

Comment: Please connect your device to computer to see the `logcat` error when it crash and post it here.

Comment: I've edited the logcat in my post :)

Comment: Can you please call the update method before the loop that is destroying the bodies, and see what happens.

Comment: I've mentioned the update method in my question :) I've put the for loop after the update and the CreateEnemy(). I've put the log in the end of the question :) By the way the update method only create a bullet ( water ) if the condition are true.

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly a box2d allocation issue and not a phone/make specific issue. What you can do is to set the body object to null when you destroy it and you will see what is happening.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < remove.size(); i++) {
    world.destroyBody(remove.get(i));
    remove.get(i) = null;

    /*for (int n = 0; i < y.getJointList().size; n++){
        world.destroyJoint(y.getJointList().get(n).joint);
    }*/
}

remove.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I am not allowed to do the remove.get(i)=null; so I've only tried the remove.clear(); but it still doesn't work.